# Have an unknown class message, code will not connect to the class I built

Tags: swift

2019-01-07 12:23:48.653406-0500 Papa John's Workout App[81234:2963838] Unknown class _TtC23Papa_John_s_Workout_App18RootViewController in Interface Builder file.

Have an unknown class error in the RootView Controller that won't let me connect my code.

Comment: check this _TtC23Papa_John_s_Workout_App18RootViewController in your application , may be you missed something somewhere , or need to verify correct name

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd>
- Type `RootViewController`<kbd>↩</kbd>
- Click on the search result in the Find Navigator
- Fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to get sure that the class defined in code is given to the UIViewController in IB (in Identity inspector)